# Why is Sublime Text 3 adding a comma to the end of this line in React?

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3

I'm really confused by this. I write this code:

```
const goalButtons = Object.keys(this.state.goalsAndPoints).map(
    i => <button key={i}>{i} – {this.state.goalsAndPoints[i]}</button>
);
```

And every time I save or navigate away, Sublime adds a comma to the end of the map argument like this:

```
const goalButtons = Object.keys(this.state.goalsAndPoints).map(
    i => <button key={i}>{i} – {this.state.goalsAndPoints[i]}</button>,
);
```

What is going on? I can't find anything about it in my settings and I don't think this is required or even good practice for this JS?

Comment: Try in Visual Code and see how it formats

Comment: The only thing that Sublime will do to your file on a `save` is trim trailing whitespace off  and ensure that the line line has an EOL on it; anything else you're seeing is the result of a package that you have installed.